# Mapping Drupal User to SalesForce User

Tags: 7, crm

What is the best approach to map Drupal Users to the same user profile that is in SalesForce? Essentially I would want to add the User UID to their corresponding SalesForce User profile. But if there is a better way I would love to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Salesforce](https://www.drupal.org/project/salesforce) module.

> This suite of modules supports integration with Salesforce by
>   synchronizing Drupal entities with
>   Salesforce objects

please refer to [this](http://www.salesforcefoundation.org/integrating-drupal-and-salesforce-crm/) link.